# Accessing and creating text files in s3 from iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how to create and access textfiles in a bucket in Amazon S3 from an iphone? I'm trying to take some data I have and store it in a text file in the bucket if said file exists and create a new text file and store the data in this if it does not exist. I'm slightly confused as I understand how to get the object but I don't know how to access it after that.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe add a little more on what you referenced?